# rename target files in GNU Makefile

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, substitution

the makefile below processes files matching the pattern`content/%.md` and outputs the targets in the `html` directory. Source files are named with the convention of putting a leading number in front of them, like `content/01.index.md` or `content/O2.second-page.md` and so on. I would like to remove the leading `0x.` number sequence in the target file. For instance, `content/01.index.html` would generate `html/index.html`.

How can I do this?

Thanks

```
MD_FILES = $(shell find content/ -type f -name '*.md')
HTML_FILES = $(patsubst content/%.md, html/%.html, $(MD_FILES))

all: $(HTML_FILES) html/static

html/%.html : content/%.md
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    python generator/generate.py $< $@

.PHONY: html/static
html/static :
    rsync -rupE generator/static html/

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -fr html
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
html/%.html : content/%.md
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    python generator/generate.py $< $@
```

with:

```
html/%.html : content/%.md
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    file='$(@F)'; python generator/generate.py $< "$(@D)/${file#*.}"
```

Unfortunately, I can't think of a good way of doing that in make itself. I can think of one way but it isn't as simple as that escaping and it isn't safe for files with spaces (not that that matters much here since make already can't handle those).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is a bad idea to use `find` or wildcards to list files in makefiles.  This is because developers have temporary or debugging files sometimes.  It is best to list files explicitly.  This way, it forces the developer to think about their intent.

If you agree to list files explicitly, then in this case it is best to list the target files, rather than source files, and here is your answer:

```
HTML_FILES := html/index.html html/second-page.html

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(HTML_FILES): html/%.html : $$(wildcard content/*.$$*.md)
    (put recipe here, using $@ and $<)
```